# Convert iptables line to command-line syntax for CSF bash script

Tags: bash, iptables

This is the question about command-line iptables syntax.
I have the following chains in /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Fri May 22 07:51:03 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

but I need them to write to bash CSFPRE.SH for CSF firewall, so they should be in a command-line like

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.254.0/24 -o br0 -j SNAT --to-source 69.64.56.847
```

or

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.254.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

But with the lines above I have a stumbling block.
I already tried something like

```
iptables :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
iptables -t nat -I :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
```

but no success.

```
    iptables -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
```

says

```
iptables: Bad built-in chain name.
```

So still not a solution. Thanks in advance for any hint else to try

Answer (score 0):

After some tests my solution was

```
iptables -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
```